# Accept multiple Directory in parameter and merged in single file using args groovy

Tags: groovy, args

below is my groovy script i want to merged all file in directory

```
def open_file(...filenames){
    for (filename in filenames){
        File file = new File(filename)
        String[] filelist = file.list();
        List arrayToList = Arrays.asList(filelist) 
        d = new Date();
        merged_file_location = '/script/merged_allure_report_'+d.getTime() +'.txt'    
        def newFile = new File(merged_file_location)
        newFile.createNewFile()
        arrayToList.each{ it -> newFile.append(new File(it).getText()) }
        print(newFile)    
} 
} 
open_file('/script/json_file_1/', '/script/json_file_2/')
```

in this script file only merged inside in `json_file_1` but in `json_file_2` direcotry all file is not merged please give me solution what can i do ?

please give me proper solution

Answer (score 1):

[`list`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list--) will give you only the file names.  Use [`listFiles`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#listFiles--) to get a `File` in the location back and work from there.